# How to remove duplicates from a csv file without sorting

Tags: csv

I have a file with three columns: `first-name`, `last-name`, `email`

I want to remove duplicate columns without sorting files. The file is in csv format.

How I can do that? Please help.

Comment: How do you remove them with sorting? It's not even clear what language you're working in

Answer (score 0):

You can use python to remove the duplicate from a csv file. There are multiple ways in python to remove the duplicates. E.g you can use set as shown below

```
 import fileinput
 withoutDuplicate = set() 
 for line in fileinput.FileInput('<name of your csv file>', inplace=1):
    if line in withoutDuplicate: 
    withoutDuplicate.add(line)
    print line,
```

This will remove the duplicate from your original file.Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is this script do sorting or not ? also please give me exact script which i have to put in phython fie and run in linux shell.  Like my script name is aj.csv

Comment: import fileinput
withoutDuplicate = set()
for line in fileinput.FileInput('csvtest.csv', inplace=1):
if line in withoutDuplicate:
withoutDuplicate.add(line)
print line,   This is my file and I am getting error   File "aj.py", line 4
    if line in withoutDuplicate:
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented bloc